# How to successfully print out deck of 52 cards and 5 hands of non-repeating cards?

Tags: c

I want to fill and print out the deck of 52 cards, and then print out 5 hands of 5 non-repeating cards successfully, but then it doesn't work. How would I be able to fix that?

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>

 /* handy typedefs */
 typedef unsigned char card;
 typedef unsigned char pairs;

 /* arrays for the names of things */
 static char *suits[4] = {"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
 static char *values[13]= {"Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six",/
                        "Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
 static char *colour[]= {"Black","Red"};

int main()
{
  card deck[52][24],*deckp;
  int s, c, a;

  for (s = 0; s < 4; s++)
  {
    for(c = 0; c < 13; c++)
    {
       sprintf(deck[(s * c) + c], "%s of %s", values[c], suits[s]);
    }
  }

  for(a = 0; a < 52; a++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", deck[a]);
  }

  int hand,cd,winner;

  int iRand;
  int i;
  int irand;

  srand(time(NULL));       /* seed the random number generator */

  for(cd=0;cd<5;cd++)
  {

    for(hand=0;hand<5;hand++)
    {
      /* deal the hands here */

    }
  }

  for (hand=0;hand<5;hand++)
  {
    printf("Hand %i:\n",hand+1 );
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      irand = (rand() % 52);
      printf(" %s \n ", deck[irand]);
    }
  }
  /* determine the winner and print it */
  return 0;
}

void filldeck(card deck[52])
{
  return;
}

void shuffle(card deck[52])
{
  int i,rnd;
  card c;

  for(i=0;i<52;i++)
  {
    /* generate a random number between 0 & 51 */
    rnd=rand() * 52.0 / RAND_MAX;
    c = deck[i];
    deck[i] = deck[rnd];
    deck[rnd] = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What have you tried, and what seems to fail?

Comment: "deck[52][24]" - what does 24 represent?

Comment: How would you do it in real life?  You would probably shuffle the deck into a random order, then deal them out starting at the top of the deck and working your way down until each hand has the required number of cards.  You probably would *not* roll some dice and say "ok...(roll roll roll...) player 1 gets cards 10, 12, 22, 23, 31 from the top....(roll roll roll)  player 2 gets cards 47, 51, 15, 10, 11 from the top...etc".  See the difference (and the problem?)

Comment: You need to use a proper shuffle. Fisher-Yates shuffle is good. Your shuffle is badly broken. http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/

Comment: The question you asked is unclear. Please don't ever say "it doesn't work". Make it clear what you expect to happen, and what does happen.

Comment: The `typdef` of `card` to `unsigned char` is not a good idea. It doesn't add anything useful, but obscures the fact that `deck` is an array of strings. If `card` is a type, it should represent a playing card; a good type for card might be a struct that has its suit and rank as members. Such a definition will come in handy when you have to evaluate your hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `deck[(s * c) + c]` with `deck[s * 13 + c]`.